# How do I update a table directly from backend in interactive grid by using ajax in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm Using two Interactive Grid to show my data. Now I just wanted to display my data and also perform DML operation onto the selected grid by using Ajax from backend. I have used SQL and PLSQL but that's not giving me the desire output.

```javascript
function setCellsToReadOnly () { 
    var grid   = apex.region("readonly_emp_ig_id").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
    var model  = grid.model;
    var recordVal;

    model.forEach(function(record, index, id) { 
         
        // getFieldKey returns index used for given field name when accessing that field of a record. Allows you to access a record field.  
        recordVal = record[model.getFieldKey("VALIDATED")];  
        var meta   = model.getRecordMetadata(id);
        var fields = meta.fields;

        if (!fields) {
            fields = meta.fields = {};
        }

        if (!fields["EMPNO"] || !fields["JOB"] || !fields["MGR"] || !fields["ENAME"] ) {

            fields["EMPNO"] = {}; 
            fields["JOB"] = {}; 
            fields["MGR"] = {}; 
            fields["ENAME"] = {}; 
        }

       value we use Object.keys(recordVal)[0] 
        if (recordVal[Object.keys(recordVal)[0]] === 'Y') {
            // set to read only
            fields["EMPNO"].ck = 1; 
            fields["JOB"].ck = 1;  
            fields["MGR"].ck = 1; 
            fields["ENAME"].ck = 1;   
            
            // invoke the change
            model.metadataChanged(id); 
        } else  {
            fields["EMPNO"].ck = ""; 
            fields["JOB"].ck = "";  
            fields["MGR"].ck = ""; 
            fields["ENAME"].ck = "";  

            model.metadataChanged(id); 
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: You have given us some code but you have not said what the problem with your code is nor what the expected output is. Currently the question is impossible to answer because there is no [MRE] that explains what input data you have and what the desired output for that input would be.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the values of the records on the Interactive Grid using model (your code seems fine until that point); you can call

```
apex.region("your_grid").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("save");
```

To invoke the save operation for the interactive grid.

Note: To invoke it, the grid's "SAVE" attribute should be enabled.